# Unable to deploy to App Engine with colon in project id

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an older Google project account that all of my services live on which has a project id with the format `domain.com:api-project-123456789123`. I am in my project's working directory trying to execute `appcfg.py -A domain.com:api-project-123456789123 -V v1 update .` but all it tells me is `This application does not exist (app_id=u'domain.com:api-project-123456789123')`.

If I create a new project in the Google Cloud Console and use the new ID, all works just fine.

I am aware that with certain Google services such as the Container Engine Registry, they have added support for these old ID's by allowing substitution of the `:` with a `/` but that does not work here.

How do I get this ID to work with App Engine?

---

**Edit**

It may be worth noting that in the console, going to the App Engine section shows the following error instead of the normal getting started text:

[image: Console Error]

Comment: Do you see the project in https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/projects?

Comment: @DanCornilescu Yes I do.

Comment: Try clicking in the project's URL from the `Project name` column - which should select it as current project and redirect you to another page. If that works check the url of this new page in your project, it should contain a `?project=<some_project_name>` parameter, try to use that `<some_project_name>` as the `-A` option to your command (hoping there's an alternate way to reference the project ID that could be used w/ `appcfg.py`)

Comment: another thing to try is the `gcloud` utilities instead of `appcfg.py`, maybe that can process the ID differently...

Comment: Ah, never mind - I just now noticed your coment on the answer and the fact that the thread is an old one ;)

Comment: same. project was in an old format. Created a new one and all good.

Answer (score 0):

Try the domain with the numbers in the project id. Example:
domain-123456789123

Your command would be:

```
appcfg.py -A domain-123456789123 -V v1 update .
```

Comment: I am not even setup for this anymore, we started a new project as there were too many things that weren't working for the legacy project.